# CI using Bootstrapping on GLM (log link, gamma dist)?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am running this exercise on SAS but don't think the choice of software is relevant: the question still legit when I am using R or others.

I was working on medical claims data (typically having long long tail). I applied GLM with log link and gamma distribution by various covariances (age, gender etc.) and got some coefficients with their 95% Wald CI.

Next, I ran the bootstrapping, resampled data 500 time and went through the same GLM to each of bootstrapped sample separately. Then I got 500 sets of coefficients, and using them I was able to find the 95% CI at 97.5%tile and 2.5%tile.

Comparing the CIs from two approaches above, the latter one (based on bootstrapping) was way narrower than the former one. 
Does anyone have an idea which one is good or bad (and hopefully why)? One possible reason of the difference is GLM is not a model having high goodness-of-fit, which is pretty common in medical claims distribution, but even so I am not sure which CI is good.

Comment: Don't you have lots of zeroes in your medical claim data? If so, you might need to consider a two-step model to adequately capture what is going on. In other words, model a binary outcome variable in the first step (0 = no claim amount; 1 = some claim amount) and then a strictly positive outcome variable (i.e., the actual claim amount) in the second step as a function of various predictor variables.

Comment: Great suggestion. I cannot see the data right now but it should have some zeros and your approach contributes to the goodness-of-fit of the model on my data as well. How does it impact the CI by bootstrap, though? Any thoughts about that point?

Comment: For a two-step approach, you would only use bootstrap if the appropriately scaled model residuals at a given step don't follow roughly a normal distribution.